# Question about k-Connected Graphs

Tags: java

Given an undirected Graph, G, is there any standard algorithm to find the value of k, where (k-1) represents the number of vertices whose removal results in a graph that is still connected and the removal of the kth vertex makes the graph disconnected?

Thank you!
Hop

Comment: FWIW - Wikipedia calls this a K-vertex-connected graph - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard algorithm, but for a graph to have this property, every pair of vertices must have >= k independent paths between them (its a simple proof by contradiction to see that this is the case).

So a potential algorithm would be to check that for all pairs of vertices in your graph there are at least K independent paths.  To find this you can use a [Maximum Flow algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Maximum_independent_path).   Unfortunately doing this trivially will probably take a long time.  [Ford-Fulkerson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) network flow takes O(EV) time (on the graph you would use for this), and there are O(V^2) pairs of nodes to check.  So worst case time is approx. O(V^5).